# No encontro el error en mi función

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Empezaré mostrando los datos, tengo dos **Dataframes**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es **dfNoms** que viene siendo un listado de todos los nombres de las personas que hemos atendido(los nombres son extraidos de un reporte anual de personas atendidas) y su sexo pero hay una particularidad y es que hay nombres que pueden ser para hombres como para mujeres y otros que solo se ven en un sexo u otro así que la columna **verificadorDeSexoUnitario** se encarga de catalogar esos nombres que solo le corresponda a un sexo con **True** y los nombres que aparezcan para hombres o mujeres es **false** y el registro ANER se repite dos veces porque aparece como hombre y mujer y ambos registros en el verificador son **false**.

```
dfNoms= pd.DataFrame({'Nombre':["PEDRO","ANA","ANER","ANER","LUIS","ARGENI","ARGENI"], 'Sexo':["HOMBRE","MUJER","HOMBRE","MUJER","HOMBRE","HOMBRE","MUJER"],'VerificadorDeSexoUnitario':[True,True,False,False,True,False,False]})
```

luego tenemos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es **df** que vendría siendo un dataframe como 50 columnas y que funciona como registro de bienes entregados a las personas, las personas se pueden repetir en el registro pero me importa solo estas dos columnas.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Nombre':["PEDRO","ANA","ANER","ANER","LUIS","ARGENI","ARGENI"],'Sexo':["MUJER","MUJER","MUJER","HOMBRE","HOMBRE","MUJER","HOMBRE"]})
```

¿Qué es lo que quiero? Quiero crear una columna en df que me permita señalar cuando el sexo que el sexo del nombre de la persona no sea el correco, sería mas o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde **s** representa que el nombre tiene el sexo correcto, **n** es que el sexo no corresponde con el nombre y **m** que el nombre puede ser hombre y mujer.
El codigo con lo que intenten hacer esto es el siguiente:

```
df["ValidadorSexo"]=df.apply(lambda x: identificadorNomSex(x["Primer Nombre"],x["Sexo (H/M)"]),axis=1)

def identificadorNomSex(nom, sex):
for x in range(len(dfNoms)):
    if ((dfNoms.loc[x,"Nombre"] in nom) & (dfNoms.loc[x,"VerificadorDesexoUnitario"]==True)):
        if (dfNoms.loc[x,"Sexo (H/M)"]==sex):
            return "s"
        else:
            return "n"
    else:
        return "m"
```

Haciendo esto deja todo como m la columna nueva y no sé que estoy haciendo mal, además no puedo utilizar el metodo .isin(). Además trate de no utilizar bucles pero no sé como realizar esta tarea sin ellos. Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón por la que no funciona es porque al hacer el `for` siempre inicia con el primer nombre que es `PEDRO` y aparte `Sexo` lo comparas con `True` y la columna tiene `HOMBRE` o `MUJER` por lo esa condición siempre será falsa y por lo tanto regresa `'m'`

Si agregas unos `print` a tu función vas a ver lo que sucede:

```
def identificadorNomSex(nom, sex):
    for x in range(len(dfNoms)):
        print(dfNoms.loc[x,"Nombre"], dfNoms.loc[x,"Sexo"])
        print(dfNoms.loc[x,"Nombre"] in nom, dfNoms.loc[x,"Sexo"]==True)
        if ((dfNoms.loc[x,"Nombre"] in nom) & (dfNoms.loc[x,"Sexo"]==True)):
            if (dfNoms.loc[x,"Sexo (H/M)"]==sex):
                return "s"
            else:
                return "n"
        else:
            return "m"
```

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

### Solución

Con los datos de cada fila del segundo `dataframe` (`df`) vamos a filtrar `dfNoms` y obtener un arreglo con los valores únicos de los sexos ingresados para cada nombre

```
sexo = dfNoms.loc[dfNoms['Nombre'] == nom]['Sexo'].unique()
```

Esto nos permitirá saber si algún nombre ha sido utilizado para ambos sexos en el `dataframe` de referencia `dfNoms`.

Ahora vamos a ver si el sexo de la fila que se está evaluando aparece en el arreglo `sexo`, si es así entonces tenemos dos opciones, retornar `s` o retornar `m`. Si la longitud del arreglo `sexo` es `1` quiere decir que únicamente se ha utilizado un sexo en el `dataframe` de referencia `dfNoms` y por lo tanto tendríamos que retornar `s` en caso contrario retornaríamos `m`

```
if sex in sexo:
    return 's' if len(sexo) == 1 else 'm'
```

Hay un caso que no mencionas en tu pregunta pero que quise incluir porque es importante, es cuando hay un nombre en el segundo `dataframe` que no existe en el `dataframe` de referencia, en este caso `sexo` devolvería un arreglo vacío y lo podríamos incluir de la siguiente manera:

```
elif len(sexo) == 0:
    return 'No es posible verificar'
```

Y por último en cualquier otro caso retornamos `n`

Ejemplo completo (Incluí un nombre en el segundo `dataframe` que no existe en el de referencia para mostrar la solución):

```
import pandas as pd

dfNoms= pd.DataFrame({'Nombre':["PEDRO","ANA","ANER","ANER","LUIS","ARGENI","ARGENI"],
                      'Sexo':["HOMBRE","MUJER","HOMBRE","MUJER","HOMBRE","HOMBRE","MUJER"],
                      'VerificadorDeSexoUnitario':[True,True,False,False,True,False,False]})

df=pd.DataFrame({'Nombre':["PEDRO","ANA","ANER","ANER","LUIS","ARGENI","ARGENI",'JUAN'],
                 'Sexo':["MUJER","MUJER","MUJER","HOMBRE","HOMBRE","MUJER","HOMBRE",'HOMBRE']})

def identificadorNomSex(nom, sex):
    sexo = dfNoms.loc[dfNoms['Nombre'] == nom]['Sexo'].unique()
    
    if sex in sexo:
        return 's' if len(sexo) == 1 else 'm'
    elif len(sexo) == 0:
        return 'No es posible verificar'
    else:
        return 'n'

df["ValidadorSexo"] = df.apply(lambda x: identificadorNomSex(x["Nombre"],x["Sexo"]),axis=1)

print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
   Nombre    Sexo            ValidadorSexo
0   PEDRO   MUJER                        n
1     ANA   MUJER                        s
2    ANER   MUJER                        m
3    ANER  HOMBRE                        m
4    LUIS  HOMBRE                        s
5  ARGENI   MUJER                        m
6  ARGENI  HOMBRE                        m
7    JUAN  HOMBRE  No es posible verificar
```